FFmpeg/Next.js15 How to serve converted MKV stream to MP4 stream
I am trying to serve a video stream using Next.js 15, and using FFmpeg to convert the video stream from MKV to MP4 so it can display on a majority of web browsers. I seem to be able to convert it successfully returning a 200 status code but nothing seems to pop up. Perhaps I am serving the converted chunks wrongly.
/app/api/stream/route.ts
import { spawn } from "child_process";

export async function GET(request) {
  const mkvStream = getMKVStream();
  const ffmpeg = spawn("ffmpeg", [
    "-i", "pipe:0",
    "-f", "mp4",
    "-movflags", "frag_keyframe+empty_moov",
    "-c:v", "copy",
    "-c:a", "aac",
    "pipe:1"
  });
  
  mkvStream.pipe(ffmpeg.stdin);
  
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ffmpeg.stdout.on("data", (chunk) => {
      resolve(new Response(chunk, { headers:
        { "Content-Type": "video/mp4", "Cache-Control": "no-cache" } }));
    });

    ffmpeg.stderr.on("data", data => {
      console.error(`FFmpeg error: ${data}`);
    });

    ffmpeg.on("error", error => {
      console.error(`FFmpeg process error: ${error}`);
      reject(new Response("Error in FFmpeg processing", { status: 500 }));
    });

    ffmpeg.on("close", code => {
      if (code !== 0) {
        console.error(`FFmpeg exited with code ${code}`);
        reject(new Response("Error in FFmpeg processing", { status: 500 }));
      }
    });

/app/Video.ts
"use client";
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Video() {
  const vidRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (vidRef.current) {
      vidRef.current.src = "/api/stream";
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <video
      ref={vidRef}
      control
      autoPlay
      style={{ width: "100%", height: "auto"  }}
    />
  );
}

